# sql delete result from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have two tables, same structure

- `clients` contains row 1+2
- `clients3` only row 2

I want to delete row 2 in the `clients` table

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM clients 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients3 WHERE clients3.id = clients.id))
```

gives me the row 2. But I do not know how to delete.

```
DELETE * 
FROM clients 
WHERE (SELECT * 
       FROM clients 
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients3 WHERE clients3.id = clients.id))
```

does not work.

Comment: remove that `*` in `delete * from...` query and then try

Answer (score 2):

You need to create temporary table for the subquery,

```
DELETE 
FROM clients 
WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID FROM clients WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients3 WHERE clients3.id = clients.id)
    ) x
)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to refer `clients` table twice in your query and remove `*` from `DELETE` clause -

```
DELETE c1
FROM clients c1
INNER JOIN clients3 c3 ON c3.id = c1.id --INNER JOIN will work as EXISTS for 1-1 Relation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Delete from clients where id  in(select clients3.id from clients3)
```