# Deleting all rows which contain a unique value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database and my dataset is really messed up. The column of importance is the a "uniqueidentity" number where some records have "&&" or "%%" in contained at the end of the value. If it does, I would like to delete the entire row from the table. uniqueidentity = VARCHAR

Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this using a SQL Query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The characters `%%, &&` always appear exactly at the end?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes - use string comparison or SUBSTR to find the rows. then DELETE them.

Comment: Don't use `SUBSTR()`, use `RIGHT()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, they do. It's weird.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, I have... I will update the question with what I have tried already before these answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE RIGHT(uniqueidentity, 2) = "&&" OR RIGHT(uniqueidentity, 2) = "%%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE 
     uniqueidentity REGEXP '%%$' OR 
     uniqueidentity  REGEXP '&&$';
```

I have created supporting [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2c1d6/5) with select query which you can change it to delete as above.

Answer (score 1):

know thy sql commands young one and all troubles will begone

[sql delete result from query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997586/sql-delete-result-from-query)

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csFall2013/cs329/lectures/sql.html

[SQL - how to select words with certain values at the end of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324012/sql-how-to-select-words-with-certain-values-at-the-end-of-word)